# Can SQL Server auto-timeout a DEK obtained from Azure Key Vault?

Tags: sql-server, azure, security, azure-sql-database, azure-keyvault

Consider an SQL Server in Azure with [transparent data encryption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx) enabled, and with the use of [Azure Key Vault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn198405.aspx) for key management. Data is encrypted at-rest in the Azure data center in <whatever> country, but the Key Vault sits on-premise in the customer's own data center.
Applications (also hosted in Azure and thus being physically placed in <whatever> country) can access the database from the time a successful round-trip to the Key Vault has been made.

1. To what entity is the data access bound (which entity holds the symmetric key)? Is it the database that holds the symmetric key so that all incoming connections will be able to see the unencrypted data? Or is the key stored per connection so that the database re-connectes to Key Vault when each new connection is established?
2. We would like to be able to shut down the database access, solely by shutting down the on-premise Key Vault. That is: no matter what happens to the data center, data access in the cloud can always be stopped from the Key Vault. Data can be decrypted only because the key is cached somewhere. Can we force the caching to timeout after, say X, seconds, thereby forcing the database to reconnect to Key Vault and ask for the key again? This would allow us to shut down the Key Vault, rendering the data useless after these X seconds.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't support an external DEK - it is stored in the database encrypted by the DEK protector, a cert or asymmetric key which can be in the Key Vault. In this scheme, the key vault is not needed on every I/O, but there is a timeout after which SQL Server needs the key vault to unwrap the DEK again.

Comment: I have tried to find some documentation about this timeout, but without luck. Can you point me to it?